# Borderlands pre sequel not launching TVHM

Tags: technical-issues, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

My borderlands the pre sequel isn't letting me go to true vault hunter mode. It did show me the pop up and everything but when I went to go in it just stays at the loading screen and won't spawn. I have no idea what to do I thouht my PS3 over heating would cause this but I could go right into the normal mode no problem.

Comment: Is it a digital download or a bluray?